# Hive query for multiple case conditions

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I'm tying to do join the below two tables based on conditions mentioned

```
Table1
ip        ts
10.1.12  11:25:54
10.1.14  09:45:25
10.1.15  18:21:45
10.1.19  10:56:45


Table2
ipaddress start      end       macaddr
10.1.12   10:30:56   15:50:20    abc
10.1.13   11:34:36   18:40:22    def
10.1.14   08:15:23   10:51:54    ijk
10.1.15   15:52:45   21:56:45    abc
10.1.16   07:45:32   23:02:56    abc
10.1.14   15:56:45   20:23:54    def
10.1.15   17:54:45   19:56:45    abc
```

1) All IP's from table1 should be looked up in the second table where the timestamp should present between start and end time from `table2`. Since Hive only supports eqi joins, I decided to join to `table2` based on `ipaddress` and add a new column to check for the timestamp match condition using case statement.

```
SELECT 
a.ip, a.ts, b.ipaddress, b.start, b.end, b.macaddress, 
CASE 
  WHEN a.ts BETWEEN b.start AND b.end THEN 'MATCH'
ELSE 
  NULL 
END AS status 
FROM table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.ip = b.ipaddress
```

The above code gives me the result

```
ip        ts        ipaddress  start       end      macaddr status
10.1.12  11:25:54   10.1.12   10:30:56   15:50:20    abc    MATCH
10.1.14  09:45:25   10.1.14   08:15:23   10:51:54    ijk    MATCH
10.1.14  09:45:25   10.1.14   15:56:45   20:23:54    def    NULL
10.1.15  18:21:45   10.1.15   15:52:45   21:56:45    abc    MATCH
10.1.15  18:21:45   10.1.15   17:54:45   19:56:45    abc    MATCH
10.1.19  10:56:45   NULL      NULL       NULL        NULL   NULL
```

2) I need to check in the `MATCH` condition's `ip`, and if it is being assigned to more than one `macaddr` at the given time, then set the status to `MULTIPLE`.  From the above example 10.1.15 is in `MATCH` condition and it has 2 `macaddress`'s at the given time.

How can I achieve this from the above table.

Comment: Do you specifically want to populate them saying multiple, or do you want to eliminate those records?